# Android App Stopped Error :inflating class android.widget.ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity_SourceDepotList">



<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogOut"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:text="Oturumu Kapat"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@android:id/list"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtCikisDepo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.widget.ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="369dp"
    android:layout_height="655dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/black"
    android:divider="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogOut"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

</android.widget.ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCikisDepo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Lütfen Çıkış Deposu Seçiniz"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@android:id/list"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnLogOut"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I take this error and application stopped

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxx.xxxx.Activity_xxxx}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
> at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:419)
> at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2669)
> at com.xxxx.xxxxx.Activity_SourceDepotList.onCreate(Activity_SourceDepotList.java:47)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable android:color/primary_text_light with resource ID #0x1060003
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_light.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060003
> at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:820)
> at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:630)
> at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:886)
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
> at android.widget.ListView.(ListView.java:237)
> at android.widget.ListView.(ListView.java:223)
> at android.widget.ListView.(ListView.java:219)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
> 2020-06-25 10:10:50.846 10572-10572/com.xxxx.xxxxx E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
> at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:419)
> at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2669)
> at com.xxxx.xxxxx.Activity_SourceDepotList.onCreate(Activity_SourceDepotList.java:47)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
> at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:189)
> at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
> at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
> at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
> at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
> at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:807)

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace; that whole section of red lines.

Comment: @MikeM. ı changed it

Comment: There should be more than that.

Comment: @MikeM. all error here :)

Comment: Which Android version are you testing on?

Comment: @MikeM. application working on API 29 but when i test on API 27 or  API 28 not working

Comment: Hmm, OK. Well, it's the `android:divider="@android:color/primary_text_light"` that's causing the issue, but I would've thought that it would happen on different versions. I'd have to investigate further to determine the specific issue between those versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<android.widget.ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="655dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogOut"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

</android.widget.ListView>
```

Comment: when i try this i take this error :Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: thanks for your answer when i changed your answer id to android:id="@android:id/list" it worked for me